# Get contents of one file from Google Drive while avoiding Google's Security Assessment

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, verification

Last year, Google decided that [majority of Google Drive API's](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) would have a `restricted` scope. Apart from all the paperwork to get approval for this, the greatest problem of this is that it requires you to go through a Google initiated security assessment which ([in their words](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#sec-assess)) "*may cost between $15,000 and $75,000 (or more) depending on the complexity of the application*".

This is **WAY** over the top for what I need this for. The only thing I want is to give users of my app the ability to get the contents of a specific file on their Google Drive. This would be possible already if they would share the file and simply use the URL. But there is one caveat: users don't want to share their files publicly. And additionally, using the public URL would produce an HTML-decorated view of the file, which is very impractical.

Does anyone know of a way of a simple way of retrieving the bare contents of a file shared within the organisation of the user without going through the regular Google Drive API? My app is a web app, so I could do this from both Javascript or my server.

Comment: Have you tried applying for verification? I have only heard of people having to pay for  Gmail scope assessment.

Comment: No I haven't, because the linked Google article clearly states: "If you submitted an app that requests restricted scopes, and the app accesses Google user data from or through a server, one of the follow-up verification steps will be to get your app reviewed by an independent security assessor.". There is no "maybe" or "might" in this statement, so I could go into this "hoping" that I won't have to go through the assessment, but that is not a reliable basis for my app. But if you can point me to a resource (article or contact person) that will clearly state otherwise, then that would be great.

Comment: I think your only option is to apply for verification.  You will not find any more documentation then what there is  currently,  The only way to access google data is though the API which will require verification.

Comment: I'm sorry to see my question got downvoted. Can the downvoter please explain why? As stated, the downvote is for "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I clearly did my research; see the links and quotes. If the question is not clear: please tell me how I can make it more clear. Finally, I don't think this is unuseful, since I think this is a very common task one would like to be able to perform on an API and there will be a lot of developers that don't simply want to pay $15k or more for that.

Comment: Close vote reason [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**   Besides that point its not programming related we cant comment on how you can pay for verification.  You should contact Google for that.   Im not sure how you expect us to be able to answer this question.   (1)

Comment: No one here can or would (I hope) answer your question by explaining to you how to HACK private user data out of google without authorization.  Which is basically what you are asking as a way to get around valid verification of an Oauth2 client.  (2)

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you for your quick reply. I was afraid of that. Then I'm afraid the Google Drive API is useless for me. Even if I would somehow "magically" get through verification without the security assessment now, I think such an assessment will easily be imposed upon me by Google anyway in the future. From my experience they are very strict when it comes to enforcing these terms and conditions and I've only seen this getting stricter the last couple of years.

Comment: Well you see thats what i am trying to tell you.  In my experience by the sounds of what you are doing you would not need to pay for security assessment because you are not using one of the critical scopes.   I think you should apply for verification i would be willing to be it wont cost you more then the time it takes to go though the process.  You are one using Drive scopes, two you should only need the read scope, your not writing.  Trying wont hurt they arnt going to charge you unless you agree to it.

Comment: @DalmTo I'm sorry you're reading my question this way. I'm only asking if there is an alternative way of doing one very isolated thing (getting file contents) on Google Drive, without having to apply for a broad scope that I don't need and that costs a lot of money. I'm not looking for a hack: I want a reliable and valid solution, where a user uses correct OAuth credentials and all. That is exactly the reason why I'm researching every inch of this and I don't want to simply proceed with the process "hoping" that I don't need a security assessment.

Comment: @DalmTo Ok, I'll consider applying, even though I really don't trust Google to not impose the assessment anyway at some point in time. And once I'm offering this functionality to my users it's much harder to take it away from them again. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Google doesnt do the assessment its a third party company that does the assessments.  You need to agree to it.